# How to Get Previous Value in SQL Server SELECT Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this

[image]

I want to add a column with name "**Yesterday Amount**" where the value is Amount from previous date and same Account_No. For example, in ACCOUNT_NO = 1 where date March 24, 2014, **Yesterday Amount** column has value 100. Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

As @BenThul points out, `LAG` has an optional default value which can be used to remove the need to use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_NO,
       [Date],
       Amount,
       LAG(Amount, 1, 0) OVER(PARTITION BY ACCOUNT_NO ORDER BY [Date]) AS "Yesterday Amount"
FROM test
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=68860f379018eba769a304074f540352)

**Original Answer**

You can just use `LAG`, with `COALESCE` to turn `NULL` values into 0 (when no previous day value exists):

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_NO,
       [Date],
       Amount,
       COALESCE(LAG(Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY ACCOUNT_NO ORDER BY [Date]), 0) AS "Yesterday Amount"
FROM test
```

Output:

```
ACCOUNT_NO  Date                    Amount  Yesterday Amount
1           23/03/2014 00:00:00     100     0
1           24/03/2014 00:00:00     200     100
1           25/03/2014 00:00:00     50      200
2           23/03/2014 00:00:00     1111    0
3           24/03/2014 00:00:00     1200    0
3           25/03/2014 00:00:00     1300    1200
```

Comment: I think that instead of the `COALESCE()` call, `LAG()` takes an optional default parameter that says what "value to return when offset is beyond the scope of the partition". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @BenThul thanks - I completely forgot about that parameter. I've updated the answer.

Comment: That's tidy! :)

Answer (score 2):

*Untested*

```
select Table.ACCOUNT_NO, Table.Date, Table.Amount,
    Table2.Amount Yesterday_Amount
from Table
left outer join Table as Table2
   on Table.ACCOUNT_NO = Table2.ACCOUNT_NO
   and Table.Date = dateadd("dd",1,Table2.Date)
```

Join Table to itself on the condition where ACCOUNT_NO is equal and Date is one less.  Using left outer join will leave Yesterday_Amount null when there isn't a previous value.  Replace it with isnull(Yesterday_Amount,0) if you want the amount to be zero instead.

Comment: @KemikoSetiawan . . . I would argue that this is the better answer.  You specifically ask about *yesterday* not about the previous row in the data.  So this works even with missing dates.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your query. if not yesterday's date, amount will be 0, so this will only show amount based on yesterday's date per `account_no`

```
select t.*
    , case when dateadd(day, 1, cast(t.[date] as date)) =  cast(t.[date2] as date) then t2.Amount else 0 end as Yesterday_Amount 
from (
    select t1.*, t2.date as date2
    from 
        (select acccount_no, row_number() over (partition by account_no order by date asc) rn, amount from tableA) t1
    left join
        (select acccount_no, row_number() over (partition by account_no order by date asc) rn, amount from tableA) t2 
            on t2.rn + 1 = t1.rn and t2.account_no = t1.account_no) as t
```

Comment: It's probably best practice to use dateadd instead of date + 1

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @avery_larry, i updated to use dateadd instead